# Different scenario of IP address and domain name in rest template

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have a rest template code as:

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication != null) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        if (!authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_ANONYMOUS_USER))) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(details.getTokenValue());
            headers.set(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessToken);
        }
    }
  ResponseEntity<Foo> responseEntity =  restTemplate.exchange(<Domain name> + "/foo/1"
 , HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(headers) , Foo.class);
```

This gives me 400 bad request. But Instead of using domain if I user ip and port of the server it works.

Also the Url:

```
 <Domain name> + "/foo/1"
```

works fine from the postman, the only issue is with rest template call.

How this issue can be fixed?